# Pandas, determine profit margin based on product classification

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with several columns, the index is product_code and the column of focus is NCM code

I would like to create a new column (called Profit Margin) within this data frame that determines the profit margin of a given product code based on its NCM code

The NCM code has 8 digits...

When the first number of the 8 digit number is 3, the newly created column would return 40%

When the first 2 digits are 45, the newly created column would return 30%

When the first 3 digits are 565, the newly created column would return 25%

When the first 4 digits are 1245, the newly created column would return 20%

Else, it would return 15%

Consider the current simplied DF:

```
product_code   NCM code
    AA         30000000
    BB         45000000
    CC         56500000
    DD         12450000
    EE         99999999
```

Desired result:

```
product_code   NCM code    Profit Margin
    AA         30000000        40%
    BB         45000000        30%
    CC         56500000        25%
    DD         12450000        20%
    EE         99999999        15%
```

I have tried to write my own function and apply to the creation of a new column with much frustration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is awkward, but not undoable:

```
import numpy as np
df['Profit Margin'] = np.where(df['NCM code'].str[0]=='8', 0.4,
                      np.where(df['NCM code'].str[:2]=='45', 0.3,
                      np.where(df['NCM code'].str[:3]=='565', 0.25,
                      np.where(df['NCM code'].str[:4]=='1245', 0.2, 0.15))))
#  product_code  NCM code  Profit Margin
#0           AA  30000000           0.15
#1           BB  45000000           0.30
#2           CC  56500000           0.25
#3           DD  12450000           0.20
#4           EE  99999999           0.15
```

Comment: May need to convert my 8 digit number to a string before that ?

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter, a one-liner (even this it's ugly) :-):

```
df['Profit Margin']=df['NCM Code'].apply(lambda x: ['40%','30%','25%','20%','15%'][[str(x)[0]=='3',str(x)[:2]=='45',str(x)[:3]=='565',str(x)[:4]=='1245',True].index(True)])
```

Make it more viewable:

```
df['Profit Margin']=df['NCM Code'].apply(
  lambda x: ['40%','30%','25%','20%','15%']
  [[str(x)[0]=='3',str(x)[:2]=='45',str(x)[:3]=='565',str(x)[:4]=='1245',True].index(True)])
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
  product code  NCM Code Profit Margin
0           AA  30000000           40%
1           BB  45000000           30%
2           CC  56500000           25%
3           DD  12450000           20%
4           EE  99999999           15%
```

So basically do some good logical list indexing in a apply bracket.